# Javascript replace string which doesn't match?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, replace

Say I have this string:

```
cat hates dog
```

When i do a replace :

```
str = str.replace('cat', 'fish');
```

I will only get "cat" replaced by "fish" , how to get it works like this:

1. "cat" replaced by "fish"
2. "other string"(else) replaced by "goat"

so I will get new string:

```
fish goat goat
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regexp `\b\w+?\b`:

```
"cat hates dog".replace(/\b\w+?\b/g, function(a) {
    return a === 'cat' ? 'fish' : 'goat';
});
```

It will match every word (sequence of word characters `\w` surrounded by word boundary `\b`) and pass match results in replace callback;

Output:

```
fish goat goat
```